# knapsack with weight only

Tags: c++, algorithm

if i had given the maximum weight say w=20 .and i had given a set on weights say m=[5,7,12,18] then how could i calculate the max possible weight that we can hold inside the maximum weight using the m. in this case the answer is 19.by adding 12+7=19. and my code is giving me 18.please help me in this.

```
int weight(int W, vector<int> &m) {

  int current_weight = 0;
  int temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < w.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < m.size(); j++) {
      if (m[i] < m[j]) {
        temp = m[j];
        m[j] = m[i];
        m[i] = temp;
        }
      }
    }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < m.size(); ++i) {
    if (current_weight + m[i] <= W) {
       current_weight += m[i];
      }
    }
 
  return current_weight;
  }
```

Comment: You are using greedy algorithm but it is not suitable for the problem. Look for DP solution

Comment: can u explain what you are saying

Comment: Approaching such a problem you should know at least about existence of dynamic programming. For instance take a look at https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/class/02713-s13/lectures/lec15-subsetsum.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you describe looks more like a version of the [maximum subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem. Basically, there is nothing wrong with your implementaion in the first place; apparently you have correctly implemented a greedy algorithm for the problem. That being said, this algorithm fails to generate an optimal solution for every input. The instance you have found is such an example.

However, the problem can be solved using a different approach termed [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), which can be seen as form of organization of a recursive formulation of the solution.

Let `m = { m_1, ... m_n }` be the set of positive item sizes and `W` a capscity constraint where `n` is a positive integer. Organize an array `A[n][W]` as a state space where

```
A[i][j] = the maximum weight at most j attainable for the set of items
          with indices from 0 to i if such a solution exists and 
          minus infinity otherwise
```

for each `i in {1,...,n}` and `j in {1,...,W}`; for ease of presentation, suppose that `A` has a value of minus infinity everywhere else. Note that for each such `i` and `j` the recurrence relation

```
A[i][j] = min { A[i-1][W-m_j] + m_j, A[i-1][W] }
```

holds, where the first case corresponds to selecting item `i` into the solution and the second case corresponds to *not* selecting item `i` into the solution.

Next, organize a loop which fills this table in an order of increasing values of `i` and `j`, where the initialization for `i = 1` has to be done before. After filling the state space, the maximum feasible value in the last colum

```
max{ A[n][j] : j in {1,...,W}, A[n][j] is not minus infinity }
```

yields the optimal solution. If the associated set of items is also desired, either some backtracking or suitable auxiliary data structures have to be used.

Comment: i am not able to understand the max part of ur code if possible can u write a pseudo code.it will be more helpful

Comment: The maximum operation in the end is t obtain the actual best solution in the last stage of the optimization; after the table if filled, the maximum feasible (i.e. not equal to the initial value minus infinity) has to be obtained.

Answer (score 0):

So it feels like this solution can be a trivial change to the commonly existing [0-1 knapsack problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/), by passing the copy of the weight array as the value array.

Comment: This is also correct, but does not answer the question.